# C Help creating a Process Tree

Tags: c, fork

I am trying to create a process tree, but here is what my output is right now: https://gyazo.com/a71f4e095b69080a6d6a11edd2c0df27
The problem is I want to make it look like the diagram I drew on the right, but can't seem to figure out how. I am printing each child processes parent ID and then after doing so I am going to delete them starting with 2, then 1 (by sending a SIGKILL signal after 5 seconds).
How can I make the process tree look like the desired result? Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main()
{
    int root, t1, t2, i;

    root = getpid();
    printf("root %d\n", root);
    for (i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
        t1 = fork();
        //printf("%d\n", t1);
        if(t1!=0)
        {
        t2 = fork();
        }
        if (t1 !=0 && t2 != 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        printf("child pid %d    parent pid %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    }
    sleep(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your main for loop is run in all forks, which doesn't match your diagram.
What you actually want is that your if statements have the same structure as your tree:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main()
{
    printf("root %d\n", getpid());

    if (fork())
    {
        fork();
    } else {
        if (fork())
        {
            if (fork())
            {
                fork();
            }
        }
    }

    printf("child pid %d    parent pid %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

    fflush(stdout);

    sleep(10);

    return 0;
}
```

This gives the desired result:

```
root 5140
child pid 5140    parent pid 377
child pid 5147    parent pid 5141
child pid 5149    parent pid 5141
child pid 5146    parent pid 5140
child pid 5148    parent pid 5141
child pid 5141    parent pid 5140
```

NB. the `sleep()` is to ensure none of the processes exit before their children, at which point their children would be reparented to have `ppid` = 1 (init).

Comment: And if I wanted to delete them from the bottom up (So delete all of 2's child processes then kill 1) How would I do that? Would I use SIGKILL? I tried running SIGKILL twice but it only prints "killed" once and then exits the program and I'm not sure how to verify it did what I wanted.